# How can we know when pop-up window url is loaded (window.open)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change the URL of the page in the pop-up as soon as it completes loading ( I am  using window.open function call).
Is there anyway I can find out when the page in pop-up has completed loading in the parent window? I cannot change anything in the page I am opening in pop-up, because it belongs to another website.

Answer (score 10):

`window.open` returns a reference to that window's `window` object.

If the opened window is pointing to a URL on the same domain as the window opener, then it will have full access to that object just as it does it's own `window` object.

```
var w = window.open(url);

// If the window opened successfully (e.g: not blocked)
if ( w ) {
    w.onload = function() {
        // Do stuff
    };
}
```

The same origin policy applies here.  If the URL of the opened window is on a different domain, then the opener will not have access to members of that window's reference.

Comment: +1 for saying the exact same thing as me (however, you didn't mention what `if ( w )` meant), :P

Comment: But didn't the OP say that he/she can't change the page? Won't this overwrite the pages onload event?

Comment: I think the OP means that they don't have access to physically change the code on the page.  This provides a means of dynamically attaching a listener.

Comment: I'm 4 years late but thank you for actually explaining what's actually happening behind the scene.

Comment: @shriek It's the Internet, we're all still here!

Answer (score 4):

this seems pretty self-explanatory, but tell me if you need more explanation (or if it doesn't work, though it should...)

```
var winObj = window.open( /* lot of params */ );

if( !winObj )
{
    /* pop-up blocked! */
}
else
{
    winObj.onload = function( ){ /* do stuff here */ };
}
```

Comment: Can you tie into window events even with the restrictions of the same origin policy?

Comment: The pop-up URL I am opening is on a different domain, so I am getting error like below:
Error: Permission denied for <file://> to set property Window.onload on <http://otherwebsite.com>.